# Python logging - Make logger work with __name__ instread of passing "real" name

Tags: python, logging

I have the following logging config:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging_config: dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "test": {
            "()": "MyLogger",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "formatter": "test",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "app": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": True,
        },
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(logging_config)
logger = logging.getLogger("app")
```

Output

```
{"asctime": "2022-07-05 14:33:09,763", "name": "app", "message": "test"}
```

This works, but I want to use this logger in every module and use the following code to instantiate my logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Output:

```
test
```

This logger will unfortunately not use the correct logger.

Does anyone know how to setup the logger to use the correct logger in every module?

Comment: Please clarify the last two sentences. You're using what logger where and how isn't it the "correct" logger?

Comment: @deceze: The logger is not using the "app" logger, it is creating a logger with the name __main__ (for example) so my custom Formatter class "MyLogger" will never be applied

Comment: ok, figured it out: You can just set the logger name to an empty string. This will make the root logger use my Formatter